# Use duality to solve LPP

Tags: linear-programming

I have some confusion regarding the solution of LPP by solving its dual. I have drawn the following table to indicate possibility/possibilities. I have made an attempt to correlate the two columns but much doubt  regarding its correctness.

Please make necessary correction in the direction of arrows to clear my concepts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\bbox[border:1px solid]{
\begin{array}{l|l}
\hfill \mathsf{If} \hfill & \hfill \mathsf{Then} \hfill \\ \hline
\text{The dual has } \textit{optimal} \text{ feasible solution} &
\text{The primal has } \textit{optimal} \text{ feasible solution} \\ \hline
\text{The dual has no feasible solution} &
\!\begin{array}{l}
\text{The primal has no feasible solution, or} \\ 
\text{the dual has unbounded solution}
\end{array} \\ \hline
\text{The dual has unbounded solution} &
\text{The primal has no feasible solution}
\end{array}
}
$$

Reference: [An online LP lecture notes](https://www.princeton.edu/~rvdb/542/lectures/lec5.pdf)